# How can I prove which vector is bigger than the other one?

Tags: python, dataframe, vector, compare

I have to divide two vectors. So, I have to prove which is the bigger one to write this one in the Denominator. My vector consists of five parameters. How can I reach this? Thanks for helping me.
This is my current code:

```
import os
os.getcwd()
import pandas as pd
import loaddata as ld
import symmetryvalues as sv
import numpy as np

dataListStep = ld.loadData("../data/mpi/onlycsv/StepData")
indexStepData = 1
stepData = dataListStep[indexStepData]

leftMean = np.asarray([stepData.iloc[:, i].mean() for i in range(0, 5)])
rightMean = np.asarray([stepData.iloc[:, i].mean() for i in range(5, 10)])

#%% 
dataFrameStepLeftMean = pd.DataFrame({'leftMean': leftMean}, index=['Stride Length Mean', 'Stand Duration Mean', 'Swing Duration Mean', 'Douple Support Time Mean', 'Relation Swing Stand Mean'])
dataFrameStepRightMean = pd.DataFrame({'rightMean': rightMean}, index=['Stride Length Mean', 'Stand Duration Mean', 'Swing Duration Mean', 'Douple Support Time Mean', 'Relation Swing Stand Mean'])

print("The Result is: " +str(symRatio))
```

and:

```
def symmetryRatio(L, R):
    result = L/R
    return result
```

This is my test csv data:

```
1.00,0.80,0.40,0.20,0.50,1.20,0.90,0.30,0.20,0.34
1.10,0.85,0.50,0.21,0.59,1.30,0.95,0.40,0.21,0.42
0.90,0.90,0.45,0.23,0.50,1.10,1.00,0.35,0.23,0.35
1.05,0.70,0.40,0.28,0.57,1.25,0.80,0.30,0.28,0.38
0.95,0.75,0.45,0.30,0.60,1.15,0.85,0.35,0.30,0.42
```

**EDIT:**
when I calculate the mean values over the ten columns, I get these ten values:
1,0.8,0.44,0.244,0.552,1.2,0.9,0.34,0.244,0.382

After that I have two array's or two vectors "leftMean" and "rightMean".

leftMean includes: 1,0.8,0.44,0.244,0.552

rightMean includes: 1.2,0.9,0.34,0.244,0.382

Then I divide leftMean by rightMean (see the method symmetryRatio). It should be so, that the larger value is in the denominator.

For example: the last value in LeftMean is larger than the last value in rightMean. So I have to change the values to divide 0.382 by 0.552 and not 0.552 by 0.382.

How can I implement this?

(I divide always the first value of leftMean by the first value of RightMean, then the second value of leftMean by the second value of rightMean, and so on)

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "bigger"? Bigger magnitude? Or bigger mean?

Comment: I want to divide two vectors. So I have to write the smaller ohne in the numerator. I think I have to compare the entries in vectors on the specific position. And then I can write the bigger value in the vector in the denominator.
But I don't know how. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: No, I don't. Are those real vectors (like mathematical vectors) or are those just data points? Can you show an expected result from the test data? Then it might get clearer

Comment: okay I try to explain it again: I have to vectors. Both with five entries (values, see test data). For the first vector: the first entry is the mean value of column one, the second entry is the mean value of column two, and so on to column 5. For the second vector:  the first entry is the mean value of column 6, he second entry is the mean value of column 7, and so on to column 10. Now I want to divide both vectors but the bigger one have to stand in the denominator.

Comment: Can you **please** add an expected result? "Bigger" can be understood differently. Do you mean the magnitude of the vector? Do you even mean a mathematical vector or a series? Further there is no such thing as a vector-division. So I assume you mean a Series of data points (5 for each vector) SO this would mean, that you probably want to divide (as you said before) element-wise. I don't know what information you get out of it, if you change nominator on every other entry, but is that what you want? Just **please** put more information in the question. Write it as pseudo-code for example

Comment: I edit something in my question above. Please look at it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you could do it, although I don't know, why you don't immediately load it as a pandas dataframe and use e.g. apply function etc. If we start after the calculation of the means:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'leftMean': leftMean, 'rightMean': rightMean}, index=['Stride Length Mean', 'Stand Duration Mean', 'Swing Duration Mean', 'Douple Support Time Mean', 'Relation Swing Stand Mean'])

df['symmetryValues'] = np.where(df['leftMean'] < df['rightMean'], df['leftMean']/df['rightMean'], df['rightMean']/df['leftMean'])
```

If you want to use `symmetryRatio`:

```
df['symmetryValues'] = np.where(df['leftMean'] < df['rightMean'], symmetryRatio(df['leftMean'],df['rightMean']), symmetryRatio(df['rightMean'],df['leftMean']))
```

Out:

```
                           leftMean  rightMean  symmetryValues
Stride Length Mean            1.000      1.200        0.833333
Stand Duration Mean           0.800      0.900        0.888889
Swing Duration Mean           0.440      0.340        0.772727
Douple Support Time Mean      0.244      0.244        1.000000
Relation Swing Stand Mean     0.552      0.382        0.692029
```

Comment: Thank you. You choose the larger value for the numerator. But I wanted the larger value in the denominator.

Comment: Oh, sorry, but then just turn it around

Comment: No problem. And I also have to use the method symmetryRatio.

Comment: Why? this is faster and better to read. The method symmeryRatio is a bit unnecessary, it is just a division wrapped in a function you could easily change any `x = symmetryRatio(L,R)` to `x = L/R`. No need to put that in a function.

Comment: Yeah okay I understand but I should do it that way. That's my exercise.

Comment: See edit, and for the future please include everything in your question, that might be of importance. Nothing in your question said, that this was the case. No one can know things like that without you having told it before ;) And also be a bit more precise when asking questions then you won't have to wait so long for an answer ;)

Comment: Okay. Thank you :)

Comment: And please don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your problem so others know, that it is correct

Comment: Alright. Thank you. :) Could you explain me that: `df['symmetryValues'] = np.where(df['leftMean'] < df['rightMean'], symmetryRatio(df['leftMean'],df['rightMean']), symmetryRatio(df['rightMean'],df['leftMean'])) `

Comment: Have a look at this: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html